# Rails 4 nested attributes with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I have been searching online and have not been able to come across an example. Does anyone know of any resources for using nested attributes with AngularJS?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of good information here and I've found it pleasant to work with. Their library does a lot of wiring for you, and I'm just starting to play with nesting the attributes but I did read on a blog that this library does it. I'll post more as I know it.

https://github.com/FineLinePrototyping/angularjs-rails-resource

Answer (score 0):

Alright just did some quick reading on Nested Attributes in Rails here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

As far as I know there's no such equivalent provided with Angular.  Generally speaking angular works with JSON encoded data coming back from requests like

```
{
  "id":1,
  "name":"Shaun"
}
```

and otherwise data is stored with Plain old javascript objects (or specific object types if a developer so chooses to create them).

There's lots of good info on various ways to use JavaScript on Crockford's site here http://www.crockford.com/javascript/javascript.html

But so far as I know you'll have to roll your own solution.  I did a bit of googling on Nested Attributes and javascript and mostly the solutions/topic seem focused around Backbone.js but you might be able to adopt the same concept and just replace Backbone.js methods with their angular equivalents.

As it stands today angular doesn't really do a whole lot when it comes to your model outside of watching for property changes and updating things during a digest.  My understanding is working on better functions for the models is a large part of what's in the works for version 2.0 whenever that hits.